# Count Distinct Assistance

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have the following query:

```
select c2.Responsible, c.deliveryname,
case..... --conditions here
end as 'PortStatus'
from table p
join table c
on p.OwnerContactID = c.ContactID
join table c2
on c.ContactID = c2.ContactID
where p.PortfolioStatus <>''
and c2.responsible <> ''
group by c.deliveryname, p.PortfolioStatus, c2.responsible
```

that gives:

> Responsible   DeliveryName   PortStatus 
>   John Doe           Peter Smith        DI
>   John Doe             Peter Smith      EE
>   John Doe            Peter Smith        hy
>   John Doe            Peter Smith        pw
>   John Doe             Bob Lee              pw
>   John Doe            Bob Lee            pw
>   John Doe            Bob Lee               ss

I would like to modify my query with a count (distinct) so that I could see 
how many unique PortStatus(es) I have per Deliveryname.

How can I get it to show me this:

> Responsible                DeliveryName       Unique PortStatus(es)
>   John Doe                      Peter Smith         4
>   John Doe                  Bob Lee                2

Comment: Seems you already know about COUNT (DISTINCT), so what happened when you tried it?   Did you get an error?

Comment: instead of the (4), I get 4 ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make use of the aggregate `COUNT` and the `DISTINCT` keyword. You also need to remove your grouping by portStatus, or it will always give you a result of 1 for each line.

```
select c2.Responsible, c.deliveryname,
COUNT(DISTINCT (case..... --conditions here end)) as 'Unique PortStatus(es)'
from table p
join table c on p.OwnerContactID = c.ContactID
join table c2 on c.ContactID = c2.ContactID
where p.PortfolioStatus <>'' and c2.responsible <> ''
group by c.deliveryname,  c2.responsible
```

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like you need to add `count(disctinct p.PortfolioStatus)` and remove `p.PortfolioStatus` from the group by clause.

```
select 
  c2.Responsible, 
  c.deliveryname, 
  count(disctinct p.PortfolioStatus) as "Unique PortStatus(es)"
from table p
join table c
  on p.OwnerContactID = c.ContactID
join table c2
  on c.ContactID = c2.ContactID
where p.PortfolioStatus <>''
  and c2.responsible <> ''
group by c.deliveryname, c2.responsible
```

It's not clear what your case expression does as you left that part out, so it's possible that you want to use that expression inside the count function if you're assigning the same port status to different PortfolioStatus values.